# Wordpress plugin for authoring technical documentation?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, cms, documentation

We'd like to use WordPress to author the technical documentation for our software product. We've used plain-old WordPress pages, arranged then hierarchically, and it works ok, but it's not great. The problems:

- The Wordpress page editor is dog slow.
- You can't drag and drop pages around to change the hierarchy
- Nothing maintains section numbering, like section 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.3.
- I haven't found a way to build an automatically-created table of
  contents on the right hand side.
- I'd like to have a  tag to highlight and indent code.

I could probably assemble a collection of plugins to do all these things, but we've already put a fair amount of time into that, and still don't have a great solution.

Confluence would be a good way to go, but I'd like to keep everything in Wordpress.

Any suggestions for good technical documentation plugins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to have to go with some plugins.

*The Wordpress page editor is dog slow.*

Throw more resources at it and/or disable some functions from showing under the "Screen Options" tab. It should not really be slow unless your have a ton of people working on a ton of pages at same time, if you can clarify what/why it is slow.

*You can't drag and drop pages around to change the hierarchy*

You will need a plugin for this , like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-page-ordering/

*Nothing maintains section numbering, like section 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.3.*

You have two options here, create a custom field meta box called " Sections" and enter a number for the value on each page, this is simple to query and display, but does not have any built in hierarchy. Option 2 would be to use categories ( or a custom taxonomy) for pages, and have them as a hierarchy ( this also allows for easier slugs), or just use a [CPT](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types).

*I haven't found a way to build an automatically-created table of contents on the right hand side.*

There are various plugins for this, search wordpress.org for "TOC". Or if you use the methods mentioned above you can use some built in WordPress functions ( esp if you create a section taxonomy).

*I'd like to have a tag to highlight and indent code.*

I like this one, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/, but there are others that are good on .org.

Comment: Though this is a pretty old comment. There appears to be a product now that meets these requirements called http://www.wpdocs.co

Answer (score 2):

I use WordPress for documentation. I use the following plugins

For table of contents on the right of the pages, I use a plugin named 'table of contents plus.' I use a short code [toc] to insert a TOC in pages.

For ordering pages hierarchically, I use a plugin named 'CMS page tree view.' This allows you to drag and drop pages or group of pages around.

Mine was a changeover from Robohelp to WordPress, and I needed a page navigation tree on the lef side bar. I use a plugin named 'wp-page tree' for this.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this plugin called [Table of content](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-table/).

Comment: Without a link this is not an answer.